# 'R' wildcard replacement

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace everything begin with "http://" with "ADDR".

I run `gsub ("http://*", "ADDR", df)`.

I have `"http://www.google.com"` -> `"ADDRwww.google.com"`.

But I want `"ADDR"` as output.

Comment: `gsub ("http://.*", "ADDR", df)`

Comment: @falsetru, that doesn't work

Comment: No, I got it working. gsub ("http://.*"...)

Comment: There was a typo. But I couldn't edit it when this was deleted ;). now fixed.

Comment: this solves my problem, I am wondering why do I need . or ^ there?

Comment: The `*` operator is quantifying the preceding character (`/`) "zero or more" times. The `.` means any single character except newline in context. So, `.*` will eat up the remaining characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

your regex is wrong. You can use anchors to guarantee that the beginning starts with http.

```
test_string <- "http://www.google.com"

new_string <- gsub("^http://.*", "ADDR", test_string, perl = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

The '*' means none or more, so you should use 'http://.*' or 'https?://.*'

vi test
insert:
http://www.google.com

```
awk '{ gsub(/http:\/\/.*/, "ADDR"); print }' 'test'
```

you will get the result: "ADDR"

Comment: he wants to replace just the `http://`

Comment: you want to use r since that's the question?